# Given mean and standard deviation for weight of CDs, find the average weight for boxes holding CDs

Tags: statistics

A box holds 100 CDs. Average weight of a CDs is 1 ounce with a standard deviation of 0.05 ounces. The box is considered overweight if it weighs more than 100.4 ounces. 400 boxes are shipped.

a) What is the probability that the average weight of 400 boxes is over 100.4 ounces?

b) Assume 400 boxes with 10 CDs each are shipped. What is the probability that the average weight is over 10.1 ounces?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know anything about what the mean and standard deviation of a sum of random variables is?

Comment: Well for part a, I'm trying to create a Normal distribution for the boxes so that I can standardize it and find the probability. I can't remember the property, but I know I can assume the expected value for the weight of the box to be 1 ounce/CD * 100 CDs, but I don't know how to find the standard deviation.

Comment: The standard deviation is multiplied by the _square root_ of the number of CD's, so for one box the mean is $100$ ounces and the standard deviation is $0.5$ ounces.

Comment: Oh, I see. So if X is the random variable for the weight of the CD, E[X] = 1 and SD = 0.05. If Y is the rv for the weight of the box, E[Y] = 100 and SD = 0.5. Then, by applying the central limit theorem, I can approximate the sample mean where n = 400 to be ~ N(100, $0.5^2$/400).

Comment: Is that right? Because then when I standardize it I get P(Z > 16)